# How to enable a custom language in Android Phone?

Tags: android, frameworks, locale

I am novice in android platform & I'd like to use Bengali as language for android phone.

In the latest release it says: **Expanded I18N support (full worldwide encodings, more locales)**
Does it mean it has by default support for Bengali or such languages?

Or still I need to do framework translation and submit to google under opensource project etc etc? 
If so I am thinking to **take it as my semester project** (atleast I can convert some part of the android os and test it in the emulator?) Please let me know what do you think..

And thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it mean it has by default support for Bengali or such languages?

Unless Bengali is known by another name, then no, [Bengali is not supported in Android 2.3](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.html#locs). I am unclear what "such languages" entails.

> Or still I need to do framework translation and submit to google under opensource project etc etc?

At best. [Please coordinate with them first](http://source.android.com/community/index.html).

Comment: It is [sixth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers) most widely used language in the world. It has unicode implementation. And I am just confused how deep I need to understand the source code in order to do the translation? I have 20 days at my hand.

Comment: @newcomer: It is rather unlikely that you will be able to supply a complete translation, test it, and have it accepted in 20 days. Regardless, the proper place for you to be asking these questions is on one of the source.android.com Google Groups, probably `android-contrib`.